# Is there a way to use MongoDB without ORM in Laravel 5?

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

Basically, I see Eloquent (for that matter, any ORM) as overhead, as MongoDB itself deals with document objects.
I am looking to use native PHP MongoDB code with application wide database connection object, for a greater performance.
Any library or a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using the standard [PHP MongoDB driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) in your Laravel app? This is the officially supported driver which most PHP ODM/ORMs build on.

Comment: In fact, I ended up doing the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read a few things and used PHP MongoDB driver with custom "Model" code, with base class like below:

AppModel.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use MongoClient;
use MongoId;
use Log;

class AppModel {

    public $collection;

    public function __construct() {
        $mongo = new MongoClient();
        $model_name = (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();
        $collection_name = str_plural(strtolower($model_name));
        $this->collection = $mongo->selectCollection('proj_zabbit', $collection_name);
    }

    public function findById($id) {
        return $this->collection->findOne(array(
            '_id' => new MongoId($id)
        ));
    }

    // more wrapper functions ..

}
```

Extended model class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Message extends AppModel {

}
```

In Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Message;

class MessagesController extends Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Message = new Message;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $id = Input::get('id');
        $message = $this->Message->findById($id);
        return $message;
    }

}
```